# Mock new instance created through reflection using PowerMockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, reflection, mockito, powermockito

I've got a class called `ConfigReferenceProcessor` that is responsible for instantiating new objects of a given type and configuring them using the provided configuration information. The type of the object that is instantiated must derive from an abstract base class called `BaseConfigurable` (There are methods defined in this base class that I need to call in order to configure the new instance). **A note going forward: `BaseConfigurable` is out of my control, so I can't make any changes to its code.**

I'm trying to unit test the method `processConfigReference`, which does the following:

```
public <T extends BaseConfigurable> T processConfigReference(
        Class<T> clazz, ConfigReferenceCfg configRef) {
    // All this in a try/catch
    Class<? extends T> objClass = Class.forName(configRef.getClassName())
                                       .asSubclass(clazz);
    Constructor<? extends T> constructor = objClass.getConstructor();
    T obj = constructor.newInstance();

    // Some methods to setup and configure the new instance, including:
    obj.loadConfig(configRef.getConfigName());

    return obj;
}
```

In my unit test, I need control over the `loadConfig` method because I don't want to drag in the entire configuration behaviour with file system lookups, etc. My first thought was to simply create my own mock object:

```
static class MockConfigurable extends BaseConfigurable {

    @Override
    public void loadConfig(String configName) {
        // Do nothing.
    }

    // Mandatory methods
}
```

Unfortunately, **I can't override `loadConfig` because it's declared as `final` in the base class**.

I found other questions on stack overflow about mocking object creation using the PowerMockito method `whenNew` and tried using that to set up my mock by mocking the final method and also returning the mock object when new instances are created:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ TestConfigReferenceProcessor.MockConfigurable.class, ConfigReferenceProcessor.class })
public class TestConfigReferenceProcessor {
    static class MockConfigurable extends BaseConfigurable {
        // Mandatory methods
    }

    @Mock private MockConfigurable mockConfigurable;

    @Before
    public void initializeMockConfigurableInstance() throws Exception {
        doNothing().when(mockConfigurable).loadConfig(any(String.class));
        whenNew(MockConfigurable.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(mockConfigurable);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldProcessConfigRef() {
        MockConfigurable result = 
                ConfigReferenceProcessor.forClass(MockConfigurable.class)
                                        .processConfigReference(configRefCfg);

        // Fails!
        verify(mockConfigurable).loadConfig(any(String.class));
    }
}
```

But this approach doesn't seem to work for me. I suspect it doesn't work because I'm not actually creating an object using `new`.

Is there any other way to get around this problem?

Comment: You are right to doubt that you can override or mock basic Java reflection stuff like `constructor.newInstance()` but there still might be something you can do earlier on.  Can you give more information about how `constructor` comes into the picture?  Maybe we could do something there.

Comment: @jhericks I'll edit the post to include more details on the reflection part, but effectively, I use a `Class.forName` to load the class. The exact class I need to load is specified in the `configRef` argument, so the class I pass in is just used to verify that the class I am loading is a subclass (I have many different subfamilies of classes that are all derived from `BaseConfigurable`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BaseConfigurable` is out of your control and `loadConfig` is final, but you can do what you want with `ConfigReferenceProcessor` right? I think a good way to go, then, would be to separate things with another level indirection.  Create a `ConfigurableFactory` class with a `newConfigurable` method.  Then you can mock the factory and verify the interactions.  So, create the factory class:

```
public class ConfigurableFactory {
    public <T extends BaseConfigurable> T newConfigurable(Class<T> clazz, String className) throws Exception {
        Class<? extends T> objClass = Class.forName(className)
                .asSubclass(clazz);
        Constructor<? extends T> constructor = objClass.getConstructor();
        return constructor.newInstance();
    }

}
```

Then refactor your original method thus:

```
public class ConfigReferenceProcessor {

    private ConfigurableFactory configurableFactory = 
        new ConfigurableFactory(); // default instance

    public void setConfigurableFactory(ConfigurableFactory configurableFactory) {
        this.configurableFactory = configurableFactory;
    }

    public <T extends BaseConfigurable> T processConfigReference(
            Class<T> clazz, ConfigReferenceCfg configRef) throws Exception {
        T obj = configurableFactory.newConfigurable(clazz, configRef.getClassName());

        // Some methods to setup and configure the new instance, including:
        obj.loadConfig(configRef.getConfigName());

        return obj;
    }

}
```

Something like this would test your method:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(BaseConfigurable.class)
public class ConfigReferenceProcessorTest {

    // public class so the constructor is callable
    public static class MockConfigurable extends BaseConfigurable {
        // Mandatory methods
    }

    @Mock
    private ConfigReferenceCfg configRefCfg;
    @Mock
    private ConfigurableFactory configurableFactory;
    @Mock
    private MockConfigurable mockConfigurable;
    @InjectMocks
    private ConfigReferenceProcessor processorUT;

    @Test
    public void shouldProcessConfigRef() throws Exception {
        final String className = MockConfigurable.class.getName();
        given(configRefCfg.getClassName()).willReturn(className);
        given(configRefCfg.getConfigName()).willReturn("testName");
        given(configurableFactory.newConfigurable(MockConfigurable.class, className)).
            willReturn(mockConfigurable);
        MockConfigurable result =
                processorUT.processConfigReference(MockConfigurable.class, configRefCfg);
        assertThat(result, is(mockConfigurable));
        verify(mockConfigurable).loadConfig("testName");
    }
}
```

You can then write separate tests of the factory class, but those won't require any mocks - just pass in the values and get and instance and check that the class of the instance is what you expect it to be.

Comment: Good idea, but this still has the problem of `loadConfig` being `final` in `BaseConfigurable`. I can't override it in my mock object.

Comment: Right, I missed that at first.  I re-wrote the answer to reflect that.  (It's quite different now.)  Hope it works for you.

Comment: Ah, clever! It feels a little strange to introduce that factory and the setter for the sole purpose of testing, but it looks like this does solve the problem rather nicely. I've put in a ticket to the owner of the configuration classes to pull the methods I need up to an interface, but I don't know if or when that change will be made. In the mean time, it looks like I can move forward with this approach. Thanks!